# Elastic Load Balancer Redirects to ELB Domain Name (Instead of keeping custom domain)

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I'm not sure what I'm missing here and I am banging my head against a wall.

I would like to point my domain to a Cloudfront distribution that has an ELB origin. I have that, it is great and dandy, but all of my requests are being redirected from www.foo.com to the CNAME of the load balancer.

Is it possible to put CloudFront in front of ELB and keep a pretty domain name?

Thanks!

Comment: Your web server is doing that.  ELB *never* generates redirects to a different hostname and neither does CloudFront.

Comment: That is what I was suspecting but was having a hard time tracking that down. I'll tak another look!

Comment: This looks like an issue with CloudFront not passing the host name.

Comment: Ahha!, updating CloudFront so it passes the Host header with the request.